# Recursively grep string in a certain variable directory structure

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have a directory structure on a shared Windows network like this:

```
\\\server\share\directory\anotherDirectory\[variable serial number]\config\
```

where the variable is a 4 digit integer.  And there are hundreds of the [variable serial number] directories I have to go through recursively.

The drive share is mapped in Linux so it sees the Windows share and can traverse it.

Once inside the [variable serial number]\config\ directory, I need to grep in a .csv file that's named:

```
[variable serial number]_config_v1.csv
```

so the full path for an individual serial number file might look like this:

```
\\server\share\directory\anotherDirectory\1234\config\1234_config_v1.csv
```

There are hundreds of serial number directories I have to search through.  I've tried adapting the answer from [this SO question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267012/grep-only-in-files-that-are-in-certain-folders) with no luck so far.

If it makes any difference, I'm doing this over VPN using Win10's Windows Subsystem for Linux with an Ubuntu distro.

Can I do something along the lines of:

```
for i in [list of serial numbers]
do
grep -in "string" $i_config_v1.csv >> log.txt
done
```

??  I'm not sure where to work the leading path in, or I could run the script from the root of where the serial numbered directories start?

Comment: When you write `grep -in "string"` it's misleading as the thing in the double qupotes isn't treated as a string by grep, instead it's treated as a regexp. It's also error prone if you want to to a full-word or full-line match as it's going to do a partial match across the whole line. If that's not what you want, there are several grep options to let you do exactly what you want, but if it is then just change `string` to `regexp` and it'll be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `i` inside `{}` to delimit it from `_config_v1.csv`. Otherwise it will try to read the variable named `i_config_v1`.

```
for i in $list_of_serial_numbers
do
    grep -in "string" "/path/to/share/$i/config/${i}_config_v1.csv"
done
```